# junit test for for Login page using Mokito

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, junit5

```
@RequestMapping("nextpage")
public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam(value="ENAME") String ENAME, @RequestParam(value="ECODE") String ECODE)
{
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    boolean result = dataBaseRepo.existsById(ECODE);

  //  dataBase.setECODE(ECODE);

    if(result)
    {
        dataBase.setECODE(ECODE);
        dataBase.setENAME(ENAME);
        mv.setViewName("next");
    }
    else
    {
        mv.setViewName("loginerrorpage");
    }

    return mv;
}
```

// I need the junit test for login page i am new to testing..
// Additional information.

// in the code dataBaseRepo is a interface reference
//for private DataBaseRepo dataBaseRepo;
//and database is reference for class DataBaseImplementaion dataBase = new DataBaseImplementaion();

Comment: What have you tried so far?